# How to refactor below codes to make better performance?

Tags: c#, performance, refactoring

how can i refactor my below C# codes to make my process for better performance?

```
var list= new List<TEST>();
foreach(var id in ids) 
{
    var list1= helper.method(id);

    foreach(var path in list)
    {
        var match = list1.Any(s => s.ChildId == path.ChildId);
        if (!match) 
        {
            list1.Add(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your profiler say? How far from your performance target are you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on CodeReview.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Dictionary<string, TEST> t = helper.GETID(id)
                                                                 .ToDictionary(path => path.ChildId, path => path);
```

If you really need a `List<TEST>`, you may do:

```
List<TEST> list = t.Select(kv => kv.Value).ToList();
```

---

If you have **too many** elements, you can rely on paralell processing:

```
Dictionary<string, TEST> dic= helper.GETID(id)
                                                             .AsParallel()
                                                             .ToDictionary(path => path.ChildId, path => path);
```

Comment: One dictionary for every item in `ids`(former `serNos`)?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to flatten all paths and remove duplicates according to the `ChildId`?

You could use a custom `IEqualityComparer<ClassName>`, `SelectMany` and [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example (presuming `Demo` is your class):

```
public class Demo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class DemoComparer : IEqualityComparer<Demo>
{
    public bool Equals(Demo x, Demo y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.ID == y.ID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Demo obj)
    {
        return obj.ID;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this comparer in many LINQ extension methods like `GroupBy` or `Distinct`:

```
List<Demo> list = ids
    .SelectMany(s => helper.method(s.ID))
    .Distict(new DemoComparer())
    .ToList();
```